# How to add % symbol to my textbox value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to add percentage symbol to a text box value, And it should not add to ng-model. It should be viewonly purpose. And Even soles symbol.Is it possible with angularJs Or css. Please help me out.This is my Example.

```
$scope.percent=response.percent.toFixed(1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just put the "%" in the field label? Why does it need to be in the input itself?

Comment: But I want that "%" with my value.Because input field value is percentage

Comment: Adding `%` in value will make it editable. That means you will have to handle cases when user adds multiple or removes all `%`. If this is fine with you, you just have to add `%` to your scope variable. `response.percent.toFixed(1) + "%"`

Comment: @Rajesh will it effect to ng-model? actually it should be view only It should not add to ng-model

Comment: Yes. It will. Its better to have `%` in label as @nnnnnn suggested. This way your input will only accept numeric values. This will also save you effort in parsing value to number

Comment: @ShivaGoudA You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8vvwkznn/1/). Note: This is in pure JS and you will have to take it as reference and derive your solution

Comment: @Rajesh It seems good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I understood your problem. You need '%' symbol always. Right?. If that is the case then use the following code.

https://jsfiddle.net/scottux/sxh22hfz/

```
.filter('percent', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (!input || isNaN(input)) {
            return;
        } else {
            return input + '%';
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are `parsers` and `formatters` on the `ngModelController`. These allow you to manipulate the `ngModel` value that is displayed in the view and saved to the model.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters

Here's a Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/y9lLc8gHTrT9bmoOG77u?p=preview

Comment: Can you please give me some example

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam - I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: plus 1, Is it possible to keep always percentage in the view. I mean when Entering

Comment: It is possible, but I'm a little out of practice with Angular, so not sure how at the moment.